# How to access custom fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-field

How to access custom fields in javascript?

I have Account with both standard and custom fields. I use the default Page Layout to display and edit any acc. It is necessary to populate some of fields in javascript, so I need access to each of them.

Standart Account fields have a readable ids, such as acc1, acc15, acc16 (see attachments). They are the same for each account.

[image]

But custom fields have unique ids, so I cant identify them in DOM (attachments)

[image]

What is the best to have access to custom fields on standard Account Page Layout?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a Visualforce Page for this already?

Comment: Do you want to do this purely in javascript or do you have a controller that you can utilise?

Comment: I already have a controller and I could utilize this.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and post the code you already have?

Comment: You need this where? VF page, inline VF, standard layout?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm newer in SF. I need this in standard layout of Account object (see above). But it is not a problem to have new inline VF component.

Comment: But the problem with inline component is that you can not (at least that's not easy) access a main page from the iFrame where component is placed (of course if you need to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there are a lot of solution for prepopulating fields on the standard layout page.

- The first and a very dirty solution is to get the field ID from the page code and save it to some custom setting to be able to access it from the javascript for example. The problem here is that ID's are all different and you will have to set up it manually (so-called LKID hack).
  Example: [New page - Parent lookup pre-populated?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23471/new-page-parent-lookup-pre-populated)
- Next possibility is to use Tooling API to find the field ID's. This solution is more clear and reliable for the production system

  - Example: [New page - Parent lookup pre-populated?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23471/new-page-parent-lookup-pre-populated)
  - Topic from Andrew: [Querying Custom Object and Field IDs via Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/)
  - Topic from Keith: [Finding Visualforce field ids](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/finding-visualforce-field-ids/)
  - Topic from Frank: [Salesforce URL Hacking (Properly)](http://www.frankneezen.com/2013/04/salesforce-url-hacking-prepopulating-fields/)
- Finally you can override a standard page layout with your own visualforce page and reproduce edit/save/create functionallity. Then you will get a full access to all fields you need to prepopulate. For me it is a better way to do things like field prepopulation.

As you can see there are some solutions for this problem. You decide what you are taking.

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot! As  I understand many of these approaches solve problem of pre-populating (on page load). But how to populate values (retrieved using ajax) into custom field ids on already loaded page? Good luck you too)

Comment: @AdelNazirov If you have got ID's you can set these values easily with Javascript using access to the field ID:  `document.getElementById('XXXXXX').value = XX` for the input field for example.

Comment: please check this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/is-it-possible-edit-geolocation-custom-field-in-inline-mode Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Without your code its really hard to suggest anything...

Depending on your requirement:

1. A simple Document.getElementByID may work
2. ActionFunction can also be used to invoke controller methods from JavaScript
3. You can also use @RemoteAction

For code example of these refer to my  Blog post [VISUALFORCE: PASSING VALUES FROM JAVASCRIPT TO CONTROLLER](http://sravalaparthi.blogspot.in/2014/08/visualforce-passing-values-from.html)

Answer (score 1):

The ID values rendered into Visualforce pages for custom fields are hard to get hold of and vary from org to org.

For purely client-side JavaScript I've resorted to basing the logic on the label text of a field. The data value is in a td of class `dataCol` and the label is in a td of class `labelCol`. So you can find the label and then find the data value input field in the peer td.

It is possible at some effort to get the field ID values using the tooling API (or some hacks) - see [Querying Custom Object and Field IDs via Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/). So you could do this in your controller and then reference those field ID values in your Visualforce JavaScript logic.